# Persistent graphics WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, persistent

I've a WinForms application on wich i have to draw some lines between controls. These lines need to be persistent, so i override the form `OnPaint()` event.

The problem is that, the re-draw of the lines aren't very smooth.

I'm creating the graphics as follows:

```
Graphics g;
g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, this.ClientRectangle);
```

And drawing the lines as follows:

```
public void lineDraw(Control L1, Control L2) {            
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 4)) {
        pen.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Flat;
        pen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
        int x1, x2, y1, y2;
        //choose x/y coordinates
        g.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Is there any property i can set to improve the smoothness of the drawn graphics?

Answer (score 4):

#### Goal

> An image is shown on a control (or form).

#### Invalidation

Any time the control (or form) is resized, minimalized/maximalized, partically obscured or moved around, it must be (partially) redrawn. When this happens the part of the control that must be redrawn is said to be *invalidated*.

When invalidated the control does something like this:

1. Call `OnPaintBackground`: this fills the invalidated region with the background color.
2. Call `OnPaint`: this draws the text and graphics on top of the background.

#### Why `OnPaint` causes flickering

You have overridden the [`OnPaint` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) of the control. Every time the control is redrawn you see a flash of the control with only its background color drawn in it. That is after `OnPaintBackground` has been called and before `OnPaint` has been called.

#### The solutions

- If you have a static image (i.e. it never changes):

  1. In the `Load` event: create a new [`Bitmap` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx).
  2. Fill it with the background color and draw the lines and shapes on it.
  3. Assign this `Bitmap` object to the control's [`BackgroundImage` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage.aspx).
- If you have a static image that must resize when the control resizes:

  1. Override the [`OnResize` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onresize.aspx) and create the new `Bitmap` in there. Use the control's [`ClientSize` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientsize.aspx) for the size of the `Bitmap`.
  2. Fill it with the background color and draw the lines and shapes on it.
  3. Assign this `Bitmap` object to the control's `BackgroundImage` property.
- If you have an animated image:

  1. In the `Load` event set the [`DoubleBuffered` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx) of the control to `true`. Setting this prevents the flicker you saw as it uses an invisible buffer to draw the control.
  2. Override the control's [`OnPaint` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx). Get the [`Graphics` context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) of the control and draw the lines and shapes directly on the control.
  3. Create and enable a new [`Timer` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) and in its callback method call the control's [`Invalidate` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) followed by the [`Update` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx) ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2695790/146622)). Set the timer to fire, for example, every 40 ms.

Comment: I never knew that existed! +1

Comment: It isn't blocky, but it blinks a lot every time the `OnPaint()` event is called. For example, when i move other control over the lines. In fact it makes sense, cause it haves to re-draw all the lines (can be many, but the aspect is the same for few lines) on each call.

The `SmoothingMode.HighQuality` didn't solve the problem. Neither the `SmoothingMode.HighSpeed`.

Comment: @Virtlink - You also might want to suggest using a timer to delay repaints so it doesn't go over the refresh rate.

Comment: None of the solutions had good overall performance. The current solution was change the `Graphics.DrawLine()` to the `LineShape` object.

Comment: @guanabara: I cannot imagine that my solution #1 would have poor performance. To be clear, it _does not use `OnPaint`_, and it sets the image only once when the size of the form is changed.

Comment: @Virtlink, i did not try your solution, because its not suitable for my problem. To give you an overall picture, there are numerous situations where the `Graphics` object need to be redraw. This include, minimize/maximize window, form vertical/horizontal scroll, controls showing over the lines, etc etc. Set the image only when the form size changes is not a solution for this particular situation.

Comment: @guanabara Indeed, I don't know your particular situation, but I infer from your post and comments that your graphics _do not change_ most of the time. So you should not draw it most of the time, and most certainly not recreate the bitmap most of the time. For example: minimize/maximize is the same as resizing, and scrolling can also be handled by the control itself without you recreating the image. If you want more help, you'll have to be more specific (edit) or start a new question (for a new issue).

Comment: @Virtlink - you're right, my graphics do not change all the time. But if i don't draw them all the time, they just disappear when some events occurs (like resize,scroll,minimize/maximize,control override, etc). So, the solution was to use the `LineShape` class, to connect the controls in the form. This way, i got the same result, but with the advantage that is control, and i can do whatever i want with it.

Comment: @guanabara You did not read my solution thoroughly enough, or you didn't understand it. You especially missed the part about setting the `BackgroundImage` property. I completely rewrote my post to explain everything. Your problem is solved by the first or second solution. You should not override `OnPaint`. If `LineShape` objects solve your problem, that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't use `CreateGraphics` here, and more importantly, don't use a local variable to store the graphic object.  Use the graphic object obtained from the paint event and invalidate as needed.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
  e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

  using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 4)) {
    pen.StartCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.Flat;
    pen.EndCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    //choose x/y coordinates
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
  }

  base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This's my way, its works for me

```
//FormMain.cs
private const float DisplayRatio = 6;

private Bitmap _bmpDisp; //use an in-memory bitmap to Persistent graphics
private Graphics _grpDisp4Ctl;
private Graphics _grpDisp4Bmp;
private Point _ptOldDsp;


private void FormMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _grpDisp4Ctl = CreateGraphics();
    _grpDisp4Ctl.SetHighQulity();

    _bmpDisp = new Bitmap(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
    _grpDisp4Bmp = Graphics.FromImage(_bmpDisp);
    _grpDisp4Bmp.SetHighQulity();

    _ptOldDsp = new Point(
        (int)((MousePosition.X - SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left) / DisplayRatio),
        (int)((MousePosition.Y - SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top) / DisplayRatio)
    );
}

private void UpdateDisplay(MouseHookEvent mhep) //your implement
{        
    var ptNew = mhep.Position;
    ptNew.Offset(new Point(-SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left, -SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top));
    ptNew.X = (int)(ptNew.X / DisplayRatio);
    ptNew.Y = (int)(ptNew.Y / DisplayRatio);

    _grpDisp4Ctl.DrawLine(Pens.White, _ptOldDsp, ptNew); //draw smooth lines to mem and ui
    _grpDisp4Bmp.DrawLine(Pens.White, _ptOldDsp, ptNew);

    _ptOldDsp = ptNew;

}

private void FormMain_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // like vb6's auto redraw :)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_bmpDisp, e.ClipRectangle, e.ClipRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

//common.cs
internal static void SetHighQulity(this Graphics g)
{
    g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver;
    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an older post, but you can also try setting DoubleBuffered property of the form to TRUE, read the following:

> "Buffered graphics can reduce or eliminate flicker that is caused by
>   progressive redrawing of parts of a displayed surface. Buffered
>   graphics require that the updated graphics data is first written to a
>   buffer. The data in the graphics buffer is then quickly written to
>   displayed surface memory. The relatively quick switch of the displayed
>   graphics memory typically reduces the flicker that can otherwise
>   occur."