# Borders are not being redrawn after hiding and showing windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a personal project. At one point in the project you have a menu with some buttons, and one of those buttons will:

1. Hide current form
2. Create a second form and show it through `ShowDialog(this)`
3. When the second form closes, the first form will be shown again with `Show()`

My issue is, that after showing the first form again, a certain border is not being redrawn. The object with this border is called `pnlInfoBoard`.

Here is some screenshots to show the problem:
[image]
The border appears to become transparent, and this only happens after hiding and showing the form.

I found out that the second form has no influence on this, it is only the act of hiding and showing the form. I had tried providing a fix by explicitly invalidating and updating `pnlInfoBoard` however, this appears to have no effect.

Here is the code:

```
private void btnInstructions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    //Instructions frmInstructions = new TowerTitans.Instructions();
    //frmInstructions.ShowDialog(this);
    this.Show();
    pnlInfoBoard.Invalidate();
    pnlInfoBoard.Update();
}
```

Why would this happen?
How do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695608/c-windows-forms-what-could-cause-invalidate-to-not-redraw)?

Comment: That's actually where I got the idea to invalidate and update pnlInfoBoard (object with the disappearing border). It is suppose to force an immediate redraw according to the accepted post; however, it doesn't seem to be doing anything in my code. Perhaps I am using the 2 methods incorrectly...